# JMeter gives Response code 401 Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, jmeter, authorization, jmeter-5.0, unauthorized

I use JMeter 5.5. I have an HTTP Request GET to URL_A. This will auto direct to URL_A/Authentication, then will auto direct to URL_B. The URL_B prompts username & password.

This is how my Test Plan tree looks like:

- Thread Group

  - HTTP Cookie Manager
  - HTTP Authorization Manager
  - HTTP Request

    - HTTP Header Manager

HTTP Authorization Manager:

- Base URL = URL_B
- Username = username
- Password = password
- Mechanism = BASIC_DIGEST

Headers in HTTP Header Manager:
Content-Type text/html

For Request detail in View Result Tree, I don't see line about Authorization i.e. `Authorization: Basic {some encoded strings}` (should this exist or not?). Meanwhile the Response detail contains these line:

- `WWW-Authenticate: NLTM`
- `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`

I've tried to add headers Authorization before and configure the Mechanism in HTTP Authorization Manager based on type Authorization I put on header (Basic, NTLM, Negotiate), still doesn't work.

My assumption is the username and password I provide doesn't pass to URLB, that's why it reponses as 401 Unauthorized although the credential is already correct. I'm expecting the credential to pass to URL_B, so the request will result as 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

If your system under test uses [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) authorization you will also need to supply your [Windows domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain)

In order to get more information on what's going on under the hood you can enable debug logging for the HTTP Authorization Manager by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

then you will be able to see the relevant messages in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter#ntlm)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for answerng. You're right, my JMeter is running in remote desktop server, accessed from another server. Both use same windows credential to access. I already add the domain in Authorization Manager. I got the domain from Control Panel > System & Security > System. Unfortunately it still results on 401 Unauthorized. The provided credential is already correct. The log also doesn't have any messages indicating any errors.